# Creating momentjs timezone map, no output

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I'm new to html, css and js. Thus far I've managed to create a website via trial and error and research to learn the craft but I cannot find an answer to my (assumingly) basic momentjs problem.

I'm trying to create a map based on the momentjs timezone map.

I have the moment.js file from cdnjs, the moment-timezone-js from http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.js and the moment-timezone-data.js built from http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/

But I have a hunch I've put stuff in the wrong place in the html. I've google'd for a way out but have not found anything thus far.

Thank you,
Kristian

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XbYw7/

Answer (score 1):

moment-timezone is about converting date and time values to a particular time zone, not about mapping.  The map shown on that website is not an example of using moment-timezone to draw the map, but rather it uses other data and techniques to draw the map, then uses moment-timezone to convert the current time to the time in that zone.

If it's mapping you want to explore, take a look at this [map-based time zone selection control](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).